# Buscar CEP por Rua PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

> Antes de tudo, preciso buscar o CEP pela Rua, ou seja, não tenho o cep
> e tenho o endereço, preciso descobrir o CEP pelo endereço. Então por favor,  não relacionem essa pergunta com *Buscar Rua por CEP*

### **Problema**

Tenho um código PHP que busca ruas pelo cep, porém preciso do contrário, preciso que busque cep pela rua, cidade e estado. Isso é possível?

### **Informações Importantes para Solução do Problema**

O WebService [ViaCEP](https://viacep.com.br)
Disponibiliza webservice de CEP e IBGE gratuitamente, entre as funções ele também tem a de pesquisar o CEP pela rua, porém não consigo adaptar as funções no código, da erro ou não funciona, não aparece nada.
Além de deixar o código da busca de rua por cep, vou deixar também a `função` linkada de como funciona pra buscar a rua pelo cep.

### **Buscar Rua pelo CEP**

```
  Exemplo: viacep.com.br/ws/UF/Cidade/Rua/json/
```

### **Código Atual**

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>ViaCEP Webservice</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

 <!-- Adicionando Javascript -->
 <script type="text/javascript" >

 function limpa_formulário_cep() {
        //Limpa valores do formulário de cep.
        document.getElementById('rua').value=("");
        document.getElementById('bairro').value=("");
        document.getElementById('cidade').value=("");
        document.getElementById('uf').value=("");
        document.getElementById('ibge').value=("");
}

function meu_callback(conteudo) {
    if (!("erro" in conteudo)) {
        //Atualiza os campos com os valores.
        document.getElementById('rua').value=(conteudo.logradouro);
        document.getElementById('bairro').value=(conteudo.bairro);
        document.getElementById('cidade').value=(conteudo.localidade);
        document.getElementById('uf').value=(conteudo.uf);
        document.getElementById('ibge').value=(conteudo.ibge);
    } //end if.
    else {
        //CEP não Encontrado.
        limpa_formulário_cep();
        alert("CEP não encontrado.");
    }
}
    
function pesquisacep(valor) {

    //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
    var cep = valor.replace(/\D/g, '');

    //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
    if (cep != "") {

        //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
        var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

        //Valida o formato do CEP.
        if(validacep.test(cep)) {

            //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
            document.getElementById('rua').value="...";
            document.getElementById('bairro').value="...";
            document.getElementById('cidade').value="...";
            document.getElementById('uf').value="...";
            document.getElementById('ibge').value="...";

            //Cria um elemento javascript.
            var script = document.createElement('script');

            //Sincroniza com o callback.
            script.src = '//viacep.com.br/ws/'+ cep + '/json/?callback=meu_callback';

            //Insere script no documento e carrega o conteúdo.
            document.body.appendChild(script);

        } //end if.
        else {
            //cep é inválido.
            limpa_formulário_cep();
            alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
        }
    } //end if.
    else {
        //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
        limpa_formulário_cep();
    }
};

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Inicio do formulario -->
  <form method="get" action=".">
    <label>Cep:
    <input name="cep" type="text" id="cep" value="" size="10" maxlength="9"
           onblur="pesquisacep(this.value);" /></label><br />
    <label>Rua:
    <input name="rua" type="text" id="rua" size="60" /></label><br />
    <label>Bairro:
    <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Cidade:
    <input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Estado:
    <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" /></label><br />
    <label>IBGE:
    <input name="ibge" type="text" id="ibge" size="8" /></label><br />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

### **Resumo**

Praticamente preciso adaptar esse código PHP, para usar como CEP Desconhecido.

Comment: Este WebService que você está utilizando não disponibiliza a busca por endereço, mas somente pelo código do CEP. Tem este site http://www.cepaberto.com/ que também é free que pode te ajudar, pois permite vários tipos de pesquisa

Comment: Disponibiliza sim @MarlonTiedt, eles dão até um exemplo - viacep.com.br/ws/RS/Porto Alegre/Olavo/json/, porém queria adaptar as chamadas para os devidos campos entende?

Comment: Não tinha visto

Comment: +Favorito para ver o site da API depois. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estou sem muito tempo para ficar comentando, como tenho costume.

Mas, como você me fez descobri essa API, então irei tentar ajudar. Infelizmente usar o JS puro, para mim, é complicado despois que passa a ter habito de usar o JQuery, por isso utilizei, mas nada impede de converte-lo para JS puro!

**Em geral fica dessa forma:**

```js
var inputsCEP = $('#logradouro, #bairro, #localidade, #uf, #ibge');
var inputsRUA = $('#cep, #bairro, #ibge');
var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

function limpa_formulário_cep(alerta) {
  if (alerta !== undefined) {
    alert(alerta);
  }

  inputsCEP.val('');
}

function get(url) {

  $.get(url, function(data) {

    if (!("erro" in data)) {

      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(data) === '[object Array]') {
        var data = data[0];
      }

      $.each(data, function(nome, info) {
        $('#' + nome).val(nome === 'cep' ? info.replace(/\D/g, '') : info).attr('info', nome === 'cep' ? info.replace(/\D/g, '') : info);
      });



    } else {
      limpa_formulário_cep("CEP não encontrado.");
    }

  });
}

// Digitando RUA/CIDADE/UF
$('#logradouro, #localidade, #uf').on('blur', function(e) {

  if ($('#logradouro').val() !== '' && $('#logradouro').val() !== $('#logradouro').attr('info') && $('#localidade').val() !== '' && $('#localidade').val() !== $('#localidade').attr('info') && $('#uf').val() !== '' && $('#uf').val() !== $('#uf').attr('info')) {

    inputsRUA.val('...');
    get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/' + $('#uf').val() + '/' + $('#localidade').val() + '/' + $('#logradouro').val() + '/json/');
  }

});

// Digitando CEP
$('#cep').on('blur', function(e) {

  var cep = $('#cep').val().replace(/\D/g, '');

  if (cep !== "" && validacep.test(cep)) {

    inputsCEP.val('...');
    get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/' + cep + '/json/');

  } else {
    limpa_formulário_cep(cep == "" ? undefined : "Formato de CEP inválido.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" action=".">
  <label>Cep:
    <input name="cep" type="text" id="cep" value="" size="10" maxlength="9">
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>Rua:
    <input name="rua" type="text" id="logradouro" size="60" />
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>Bairro:
    <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" />
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>Cidade:
    <input name="cidade" type="text" id="localidade" size="40" />
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>Estado:
    <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" />
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>IBGE:
    <input name="ibge" type="text" id="ibge" size="8" />
  </label>
  <br />
</form>
```

### **Como funciona:**

> Um resumo de "partes criticas" que podem gerar alguma duvida:

**Seleção de digitação:**

- Se digitar o CEP irá consultar o
  `https://viacep.com.br/ws/{CEP}/json/`.
- Se digitar o RUA, CIDADE e UF
  irá consultar o `https://viacep.com.br/ws/{UF}/{CIDADE}/{RUA}/json/`

**Conexão**

Modificado de JSONP para JSON, usando o $.get(), para minimizar a repetição de código foi criada uma função com nome de `get`.

**Verificação de Array**

Por padrão quando digitado o CEP apenas retorna uma ARRAY, sendo assim basta fazer o loop dela. Enquanto que ao digitar o endereço (Rua, Cidade, Estado) o site retorna uma OU MAIS array.

*Exemplo:*

```
Pesquisa por CEP = {'nome':'dado'}
Pesquisa por Endereço = [{'nome':'dado'}, {'nome':'dado'}]
```

Por isso foi criado o `Object.prototype.toString.call(data)` para verificar se existe múltiplos CEPs/Arrays. Dessa forma ele irá fazer o loop usando sempre a primeira!

**Atributo `info`:**

Isso foi criado para que caso o usuário digite um novo endereço seja necessário modificar todos o dados de Rua, Cidade e Estado para que faça uma nova requisição. O `info` armazena o mesmo conteúdo do `value`, por isso se o usuário digitar uma nova rua sem alterar a cidade e o estado não irá fazer uma nova requisição.

Isso é opcional, apenas para evitar de fazer múltiplas requisições. Para que seja necessário fazer a nova verificação todos os dados de Rua, Cidade e Estado devem ser alterados.

Comment: Cara não acredito, @Inkeliz muito obrigado pela resposta, essa é a solução do meu problema e de muitas outras pessoas acredito, enviei o código na integra para o ViaCep por email e pedi para que colocasse o devido crédito a você. Agradeço mesmo, já tinha perdido as esperanças nessa pergunta, ótimo trabalho amigo

Answer (score 2):

Pelo o que eu entendi a busca por rua precisa passar cidade e estado também.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
var rua = document.getElementById('rua').value=("");
var cidade = document.getElementById('cidade').value=("");
var uf = document.getElementById('uf').value=("");

script.src = '//viacep.com.br/ws/'+ uf + '/'+ cidade + '/'+ rua + '/json/?callback=meu_callback';

        //Insere script no documento e carrega o conteúdo.
        document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Desculpe, não está muito claro, o que eu faço com o o resto do script?

Answer (score -3):

Plugin jQuery recomendado pelo ViaCEP https://github.com/arthurfigueiredo/autocomplete-address